# Permanently save changes on GRUB menu

Tags: boot, grub

Any way to permanently save an edited entry in a GRUB menu during GURB menu usage, not after the system have booted and i can do that by a myriad a ways.

I know about editing the config scripts in `grub.d`, but for quick changes while I'm fixing something, and that I will have to boot into some ten times and then never more, i'd love to be able to edit an entry on the spot and save.

The [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub.html#Menu-entry-editor) does not mention anything else besides what's already mentioned on the edit screen (i.e. `ctrl-x` boot, `esc` cancel edit), but then, I had to find most available commands from the emergency prompt outside of the manual.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GRUB has read-only filesystem drivers.  It cannot write back updates to the configuration files on disk.

Comment: not even a debug mode where it mount as write mode, save the changes, and mount in RO again?

Answer (score 4):

Run `update-grub`.

You can quickly edit the resulting `grub.cfg` file to make your changes.

Comment: i know, but when you are booting ten times per minute to debug something (that may not even give you a usable state, when you are debugging setmode or apci options to the kernel/video drivers) you usually forget or don't even have image on the screen to do anything